# with ajax js, passing an array to php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I've created an string array: `'id=$id&value=$value'` with two value id+checked, I'm trying to pass this array through php to update an DB.. I'm newbie with ajax so I don't know how to do it correctly.. I did it for inserting data from a form when it works cool.. but I struggle badly with this issue. I collect the values from a table after click a submit btn, please, help out!

JS code:

```
function ejecutarAjax(datos) {
    ajax = objetoAJAX();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = enviarDatos;
    ajax.open("POST", "trst.php");
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.send(datos);
}


var datos = new Array,
     queryString = '',
     id = new Array(),
     status = new Array(),
checkStatus = document.getElementsByName('check');

for (i = 0; i < checkStatus.length; i++) {
    id[i] = checkStatus[i].getAttribute('data-id');
    status[i] = checkStatus[i].checked;
    datos += "idStatus=" + id[i] + "&checkStatus=" + status[i] + "&";
}
queryString = datos + "transaccion=upset";
//console.log(queryString);
ejecutarAjax(queryString);
```

PHP code:

```
$idStatus = $_POST["idStatus"];
$checkStatus = $_POST["check"];

updateTable($idStatus,$checkStatus);
```

Comment: `I did it for inserting data from a form when it works cool.. ` so where is HTML & ajax code ?

Comment: can you show us your `ejecutarAjax()` js function? you probably appending your querystring with url and thus you can not retrieve it by $_POST in php, you need to use $_GET instead.

Comment: There are a few reasons why this might fail, but none of them are obvious from the code you've supplied. How are you running the JS? Are any errors show in your JS console? And you see the rest in the Net tab of your developer tools? Is it formatted as you expect? Does it get the data you expect?

Comment: function ejecutarAjax(queryString){
 var array = JSON.stringify(myarray);
 $.ajax({
     url: "controller.php",
     data: {array: array},
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data){
         alert(data["return"]);
     }
 });
}

Comment: Quentin: From a html table created by php, I've got some users signed up  where I can change their status using a checkbox for each of them, Once I change their status, I may click on a submit button, then  he goes to ajax, get a function who creates the arrays string with "id user" and a "check value 'true or false' like this: 

var datos= idStatus=172&checkStatus=false&idStatus=171&checkStatus=true&';

 After that, he sends it off to ejecutarAjax(datos) function where he should open a *.php and by 'post', get and runs the function, it's in the php function the problem